# Is Laplace’s demon compatible with other interpretations of quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, determinism

We know that [Laplace’s demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_demon) is incompatible with the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics, because the Copenhagen interpretation is inherently non-deterministic.

But there are other deterministic interpretations of quantum mechanics, such as the **many-worlds interpretation** and the **De-Broglie-Bohm interpretation**. Are these interpretations compatible with Laplace’s demon?

Answer (score 0):

Laplace's demon is only a thought experiment demonstrating the absurdity of determinism. It is **not** an interpretation of QM.

Laplace's demon, like determinism it demonstrates, is incompatible with *reality.*